# Binding LINQ XDocument to Treeview with attributes

Tags: wpf, xml, binding, treeview, linq-to-xml

I want to bind my `XDocument` to `TreeView` control. Nodes work fine but I can't manage to bind attributes (I want to list whole XML file in a tree - nodes and attributes should be visible). I use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. The problem appears, because there is no property like `Attributes` ([LINQ to XML Dynamic Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669107.aspx) says that). How can I solve my problem? I searched through the whole web and even uncle Google hasn't helped me yet:S I read something about `ObjectDataProvider` and `IValueConverter` interface, but don't actually understand how to use these to solve my problem. Thanks for help in advance. Piece